# bash shell script for last-week dates

Tags: shell

I am writing shell where I am going to need dates from last week irrespective of the day I am running on. I tried below but those are somehow failing. Can you please help.

```
date --date='last Monday'
date --date='last week + last Thursday'
date --date='last week + last Monday'
```

Thanks

Comment: Why did you fail? I ran this and it worked.

Comment: @sachinbhomale Please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define on what day your week ends, and then work backwards from there. For example, assuming that your week ends on Sunday, then you can get all the dates from the previous week by doing:

```
saturday=$(date -d 'last Sunday - 1 day')
friday=$(date -d 'last Sunday - 2 days')
# etc.
```